# Optaplanner doesn't terminate when using custom filter class

Tags: optaplanner

In some cases, but not always, seemingly randomly, and using the exact same configuration, Optaplanner doesn't terminate after it's secondsSpentLimit course. it just hangs with "INFO   --- [           main] .c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase : Construction Heuristic phase (1) ended: step total (0), time spent (1507), best score (-9hard/0soft)"

Here's my config:

```
<solver>
<environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</environmentMode>

<!-- Domain model configuration -->
<solutionClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.ActivitySolution</solutionClass>
<entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.TaskPlannerDto</entityClass>
<entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.TaskResourceAllocationPlannerDto</entityClass>

<!-- Score configuration -->
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
    <scoreDrl>com/rdthree/plenty/services/activities/planner/activity-scoring.drl</scoreDrl>
    <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
<termination>
    <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
    <bestScoreLimit>0hard/0soft</bestScoreLimit>
    <secondsSpentLimit>60</secondsSpentLimit>
</termination>

<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <entitySelector id="resourceAllocationSelector">
            <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.TaskResourceAllocationPlannerDto</entityClass>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
            <sorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY_IF_AVAILABLE</sorterManner>
        </entitySelector>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="resourceAllocationSelector" />
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>resource</variableName>
                <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>

<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <entitySelector id="taskSelector">
            <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.TaskPlannerDto</entityClass>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
            <sorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY_IF_AVAILABLE</sorterManner>
        </entitySelector>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="taskSelector" />
            <filterClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.TaskLengthChnageFilter</filterClass>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>interval</variableName>
                <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>

<localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
        <moveListFactory>
            <moveListFactoryClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.MoveResourceAllocationMoveFactory</moveListFactoryClass>
        </moveListFactory>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <fixedProbabilityWeight>1.0</fixedProbabilityWeight>
            <filterClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.TaskLengthChnageFilter</filterClass>
            <entitySelector id="taskMoveSelector">
                <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.TaskPlannerDto</entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>interval</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>

    <acceptor>
        <valueTabuSize>7</valueTabuSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
        <acceptedCountLimit>2000</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
</localSearch>
```

I also have a move filter:

```
public class TaskLengthChnageFilter implements SelectionFilter<ChangeMove> {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public boolean accept(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, ChangeMove selection) {
    // get the solution
    Solution<HardSoftScore> solution = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();
    List<TaskRequirementsMapper> taskRequirementsMappers = new ArrayList<>();
    // find the taskRequirementsMappers in the problem facts
    for (Object fact : solution.getProblemFacts()) {
        if (fact instanceof TaskRequirementsMapper) {
            taskRequirementsMappers.add((TaskRequirementsMapper) fact);
        }
    }
    for (Object obj : selection.getPlanningEntities()) {
        TaskPlannerDto task;
        Interval interval = null;
        // get a task move
        if (TaskPlannerDto.class.equals(obj.getClass())) {
            // get the planning value (i.e the resource that is being changed in the allocation)
            for (Object thePvalue : selection.getPlanningValues()) {
                // the collection should only hold one value so take it and break
                interval = (Interval) thePvalue;
                break;
            }
            task = (TaskPlannerDto) obj;
            // iterate over all the task requirement mappers
            for (TaskRequirementsMapper taskRequirementsMapper : taskRequirementsMappers) {
                // and find the one relevant for this allocation
                if (task.getId().equals(taskRequirementsMapper.getTaskId())) {
                    // check
                    int newLength = interval.toPeriod().getDays();
                    int oldLength = taskRequirementsMapper.getLength();
                    if (newLength != oldLength) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Here's my thread dump after killing the process with kill -3 PID. Also, the trace logging messages:

```
2015-09-18 12:36:05.079  INFO   --- [           main] o.d.c.k.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl   : KieModule was added:MemoryKieModule[ ReleaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
2015-09-18 12:36:05.414  INFO   --- [           main] o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver       : Solving started: time spent (155), best score (-9hard/0soft), environment mode (FULL_ASSERT), random (JDK with seed 0).
2015-09-18 12:36:05.425  INFO   --- [           main] o.o.c.a.s.event.SolverEventListener      : New Best Solution Found with score : -9hard/0soft
2015-09-18 12:36:05.426  INFO   --- [           main] .c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase : Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (0), time spent (167), best score (-9hard/0soft).
2015-09-18 12:36:05.436  INFO   --- [           main] o.o.c.a.s.event.SolverEventListener      : New Best Solution Found with score : -9hard/0soft
2015-09-18 12:36:05.436  INFO   --- [           main] .c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase : Construction Heuristic phase (1) ended: step total (0), time spent (177), best score (-9hard/0soft).
2015-09-18 12:36:05.446 TRACE   --- [           main] .m.f.MoveListFactoryToMoveSelectorBridge :     Created cachedMoveList: size (60), moveSelector (MoveListFactory(class com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.MoveResourceAllocationMoveFactory)).
2015-09-18 12:39:16
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode):

"WeakCollectionCleaner" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954e143800 nid=0xd507 in Object.wait() [0x0000000115f09000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007840964c0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000007840964c0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at org.geotools.util.WeakCollectionCleaner.run(WeakCollectionCleaner.java:77)

"GT authority factory disposer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954ca1e800 nid=0xd207 in Object.wait() [0x0000000116093000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007840ea820> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000007840ea820> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"AWT-AppKit" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954e552800 nid=0x713 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"java-sdk-http-connection-reaper" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954d69a000 nid=0x5b03 waiting on condition [0x0000000115667000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.run(IdleConnectionReaper.java:112)

"Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954e0b5800 nid=0x5903 in Object.wait() [0x0000000115bba000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007816e4b98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000007816e4b98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)

"Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[1625026637:1442568952184]" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954e11e800 nid=0x5807 in Object.wait() [0x00000001157d3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007814885e0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000007814885e0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"ReaderThread" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954e08d800 nid=0x5103 runnable [0x00000001152ed000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    - locked <0x000000078056f568> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    - locked <0x000000078056f568> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner$ReaderThread.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:135)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954e011000 nid=0x4d03 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c089000 nid=0x4b03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c072000 nid=0x4903 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c02a000 nid=0x3c13 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c06f800 nid=0x3503 in Object.wait() [0x00000001125db000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000078056a588> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x000000078056a588> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c06f000 nid=0x3303 in Object.wait() [0x00000001124d8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000780597940> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x0000000780597940> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c02c800 nid=0x1303 runnable [0x0000000103374000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMoveSelector$RandomChangeMoveIterator.createUpcomingSelection(ChangeMoveSelector.java:166)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMoveSelector$RandomChangeMoveIterator.createUpcomingSelection(ChangeMoveSelector.java:129)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.iterator.UpcomingSelectionIterator.hasNext(UpcomingSelectionIterator.java:40)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.decorator.FilteringMoveSelector$JustInTimeFilteringMoveIterator.createUpcomingSelection(FilteringMoveSelector.java:90)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.decorator.FilteringMoveSelector$JustInTimeFilteringMoveIterator.createUpcomingSelection(FilteringMoveSelector.java:77)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.iterator.UpcomingSelectionIterator.hasNext(UpcomingSelectionIterator.java:40)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelector$RandomUnionMoveIterator.refreshMoveIteratorMap(UnionMoveSelector.java:183)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelector$RandomUnionMoveIterator.hasNext(UnionMoveSelector.java:159)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(LocalSearchDecider.java:112)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:66)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runPhases(DefaultSolver.java:213)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:176)
    at com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.auto_scheduler.AutoSchedulerServiceBean.autoSchedule(AutoSchedulerServiceBean.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy227.autoSchedule(Unknown Source)
    at com.rdthree.plenty.threads.SchedulerThread.run(SchedulerThread.java:104)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at com.rdthree.plenty.services.notifications.TestNotificationService.testSchedulerThreadFailNotification(TestNotificationService.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at com.rdthree.plenty.PlentyGeneralTest$RetryRule$1.eval(PlentyGeneralTest.java:46)
    at com.rdthree.plenty.PlentyGeneralTest$RetryRule$1.evaluate(PlentyGeneralTest.java:56)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

"VM Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954d00d800 nid=0x3103 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c038800 nid=0x2103 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c039000 nid=0x2303 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c03a000 nid=0x2503 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954c03a800 nid=0x2703 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954d000800 nid=0x2903 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954d001000 nid=0x2b03 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954d001800 nid=0x2d03 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954d002800 nid=0x2f03 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007f954e010000 nid=0x4f03 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 697

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 698880K, used 154259K [0x00000007d5500000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 698368K, 22% used [0x00000007d5500000,0x00000007deba4f78,0x00000007fff00000)
  from space 512K, 0% used [0x00000007fff00000,0x00000007fff00000,0x00000007fff80000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000007fff80000,0x00000007fff80000,0x0000000800000000)
 ParOldGen       total 349696K, used 92182K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000795580000, 0x00000007d5500000)
  object space 349696K, 26% used [0x0000000780000000,0x0000000785a05be8,0x0000000795580000)
 PSPermGen       total 131072K, used 85162K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000708000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 131072K, 64% used [0x0000000700000000,0x000000070532ab80,0x0000000708000000)
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about how you configure your solver? Is there any phase after Construction Heuristics?

Comment: Do you use a move or entity filter?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet, yes i am using a SelectionFilter<ChangeMove>, see my edit for more details

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's not random: If the termination criteria are fulfilled before the Construction Heuristic ends, it will terminate. If however it reached the Local Search phase (or a specific move selector in the Local Search phase), it's stuck.

I see 2 scenario's:

- If your custom `MoveListFactory` or your custom `MoveFilter` is stuck in an **infinite loop**, then OptaPlanner won't terminate. Do a JVM *Threads Dump* (ctrl-break in console, or that button in the IntelliJ console) when it's not terminating to find out the stacktrace of the current running code.
- If your custom `MoveFilter` doesn't accept any move, no move is selected, so no move is evaluated. Turn on warn xor trace logging (see optaplanner docs). In warn logging it will show a bailout warning if this happens too much. In trace logging it will show that when it's stuck no moves are being evaluated (so no trace messages).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, I know what you mean about the inifinte loop and bailouts as i had them before due to another issue with my code, but solved it, so this is not the case now, i have my logging on Trace. Maybe you could help me with the thread dump? i put it in an edit in my question

Comment: The thread dump clearly proves there's not an infinite loop (so case 1) in your code. It also shows that a FilteringMoveSelector is being consulted a lot, so I believe case 2 applies here: your custom MoveFilter never returns true. Just log (or system.out) the result of every MoveFilter call. Together with the trace logging it at a some point sending move log messages and only filter returns false message (never true).